# How do I use a CoreData model from a framework within an app group?

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm packaging a basic framework that's got some repositories around CoreData models, that package contains the .xcdatamodeld file. If I use it in my app extensions, for example, it's not in the app groups folder.

If I add the code below in my `PersistentContainer` subclass, I'm receiving the error below:

```
let url = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.{bundleID}")?.appendingPathComponent("{Name}.sqlite", isDirectory: false)
let storeDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: url!)
        
persistentStoreDescriptions = [storeDescription]
```

This is the error message:
`<NSPersistentStoreCoordinator: 0x600002ce9ab0>: Attempting recovery from error encountered during addPersistentStore: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The file couldn’t be saved." UserInfo={reason=Failed to create file; code = 2}`

How can I have a framework with a CoreData model, which is placed in the App Group for all targets to use?

Comment: This should be possible. What happens if you try to write anything to `url` directly using `FileManager`?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez It's weird, with the code above, it actually writes a database to the app group, it is doing stuff with it, but that's like all. Apparently it crashes afterwards?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Weird, it's working now. I'm confused, but well, it seems to work now.

Comment: I'll take credit for that, you're welcome :P